# MS Access, ASP, VBScript Missing Operator error

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm using Access as a backend for an ASP page. I'm using saved queries.
The table looks like this:

```
  UCall  Zone  Band
    NF4L    2    B160
    NF4L    5    B40
    NF4L    7    NULL
    AB2AB   5    B10
```

The query looks as follows:

```
Select COUNT(*) as BCnt 
From tblScore 
Where Band IS NOT NULL and UCall=[in_call];
```

The result should be a count of all rows for a given call where there is an entry for Band. The query run with NF4L as the parm should return 2.

The query works as expected in Access itself, but when the ASP page is run I get

```
"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Band IS NOT NULL and UCall=[in_call]'.
```

From the ASP page:

```
function GetBandTotals(in_call)
  conn2.BandSummary in_call, BRS
  GetBandTotals = BRS("BCnt")
end function
```

conn2 is an adodb connection

BRS is an adodb recordset

I've verified that in_call is getting there.

Comment: How are you supplying the parameter?

Comment: And you are sure that in_call is filled?

Comment: Yes. A "response.write in_call" showed it.

Comment: I have run out of ideas. It works perfectly for me in ASP using the above. Although I did build the query in MS Access, which appends the table name to fields, thus ensuring you do not get problems with reserved words.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Rather than trying to figure out what is and is not a reserved word, use the convention of prefixing all field names with the table name, or better, the alias. This will save trouble in a great many cases, not just reserved words: `select a.id, b.id, b.name from tablea a inner join tableb b` It also makes your SQL suitable for a number of other databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Band` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#B), so enclose that name in square brackets.

Also add a `PARAMETERS` clause to inform the db engine to expect text type for the `in_call` parameter.  I don't know whether that will help, but it won't hurt.

```
PARAMETERS in_call Text ( 255 );
SELECT COUNT(*) AS BCnt 
FROM tblScore 
WHERE [Band] IS NOT NULL AND UCall=[in_call];
```